# Number increment from string value

Tags: c#

I my application due to some reason I have two numbers in 5 digits.

The following code give you brief idea.

```
string s = "00001"; // Initially stored somewhere.
//Operation start
string id = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy") + DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).ToString("yy") + s;
//Operation end

//Increment the value of s by 1. i.e 00001 to 00002
```

This can be done easily by convert the value of **s** to int and increment it by 1 but after all that I have to also store the incremented value of s in 5 digit so it will be **"00002"**.

This think give me a pain...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I did not understood if storing the string "0000x" is a requirement or is your pain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use

```
string s = "00001";
int number = Convert.ToInt32(s);
number += 1;
string str = number.ToString("D5");
```

to get atleast 5 digits.

[The "D" (or decimal) format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString)

> **If required, the number is padded with zeros to its left to produce the number of digits given by the precision specifier.** If no
>   precision specifier is specified, the default is the minimum value
>   required to represent the integer without leading zeros.

Comment: If loving Habibs' ansswers is wrong, I don't want to be right :)

Comment: so nice of you @SonerGönül

Answer (score 7):

This seems to work for me.

```
string s = "00001";
int i = Int32.Parse(s);
i++;
s = i.ToString("D" + s.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think you want to know how to convert an `int` to a 5 digit `string`.

You can do this:

```
int i = 1;
string s = i.ToString("D5");
//s = "00001"
```

There are plenty of [format examples here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Format()` to achieve this:

```
string str = String.Format({0:#####}, s);
```

Look [here](http://alexonasp.net/samples/stringformatting/).

Answer (score 0):

This works using the `PadLeft` function:

```
int i = 1; // Initially stored somewhere.
//Operation start
string id = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy") + DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).ToString("yy") + i.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
//Operation end
```