# Increment formated string (f.e. "07-01" to "07-02")

Tags: c#, string

I have a string with the format 00-00 and I want to increment it to 00-01. 
Currently I am using Split() but I have the feeling that my approach is not really best practice.

I don't have to worry about edge cases and just want to know if there is an elegant solution.

Thanks

Comment: Parse -> increment -> convert to string. See e.g [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15409303/1997232).

Comment: It sounds like this would be a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com, where you'd present your current working code...

Comment: The trick is that in your code you have a class (e.g. `Version`) with some properties (like `Major`, `Minor`) and some methods (e.g. `Increment()`). Then this class overrides `ToString()` and returns a human readable string out of its values (e.g. `$"{Major}-{Minor}"`). Then you don't have to fiddle around with string split and parse.

Comment: Off topic tip: `f.e.` is not the correct abbreviation for "for example". The correct abbreviation is `e.g.`. It comes from the Latin "exemplum grata", which literally means "a given example".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq approach without edge cases like `00-99` or `99-99`

```
string input ="07-01";
string result = string.Join("-", input.Split('-')
                                      .Select(int.Parse)
                                      .Select((x, i) => (i == 1 ? ++x : x).ToString("00")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method of utilizing `string.Split()` would be my suggestion too.

However, I'm wondering if you are repeatedly incrementing that number. if this is a one time action, then I agree with using the split method.

If you are continually incrementing this number (e.g. as a counter), you will start noticing that it takes more resources to do string operations (split) and conversions (string to int, int to string); compared to incrementing the value of the integer.
In this case, I would advocate that you keep the integer value in memory, and keep using that to generate your output string, instead of always having to start from scratch.

However, the latter suggestion only applies if you keep incrementing the same values. Your question did not specify that that is the case.