# Invoice No Generating using c#.net

Tags: c#

I am creating a simple inventory system project. I want the invoice no to be auto-incrementing using the format `E-000000`, starting from *E-000001* for the first invoice, the second *E-000002* and so on.

I tried to use the following syntax but it failed.

`c = Format(Mid(dr("invoid"), 2, 6) + 1, "E00000#");`

error displayed on the Format. 
How can I increment values stored using this format?

```
public void invoiceno()
{
    try
    {
        string c;
        var sql = "SELECT MAX(invoid) FROM sales";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if(dr.HasRows == false)
        {
            c = "E-000001";
        }
        else
        {
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                c = Format(Mid(dr("invoid"), 2, 6) + 1, "E00000#");
            }
        }

        label4.Text = c;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.Write(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes sir please help

Comment: mid is Substring in c#, so something like `dr("invoid").ToString().Substring(2, 6)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number increment from string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409303/number-increment-from-string-value)

Comment: data coming from database table invoiceid colum

Comment: The data reader will only have a single result, you should be using ExecuteScalar instead, and no while loop or if is needed. Just label.Text = $"E-{dr:000000}";

Comment: how to use it ExecuteScalar

Comment: your code will give your the last value. u want all values in c or the last value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a simple implementation broken down into discrete steps:

- `maxInvId`: this is the string value of the max id in the table, something like `"E-000101"`

  - In this solution I have used `ExecuteScalar` as this result only has a single column, single row result. Internally it uses `ExecuteReader` but this simplifies your logic and documents the expectation of a single value result to the developers sho will maintain your code later.
- `intVal`: this is the integer portion of the maxInId value. - should be `101` in the previous example.

  - We increment this value by 1, now the `intVal` should be `102`
- `c`: this is the new Id for the next row, should be `E-000102`

```
public void invoiceno()
{
    try
    {
        string c;
        var sql = "SELECT MAX(invoid) FROM sales";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        var maxInvId = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;

        if(maxInvId == null)
        {
            c = "E-000001";
        }
        else
        {
            int intVal = Int.Parse(maxInvId.Substring(2, 6));
            intVal ++;
            c = String.Format("E-{0:000000}", intVal);
        }

        label4.Text = c;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.Write(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: no error displayed when i call the invoiceno() on formload id is not displayed

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with the debugger to inspect the values returned? for instance, what is the value of maxInvId, what is the value of intVal?

Comment: thanks sir it working.........................

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as this. The SQL result will only have 1 scalar value, so you should use `ExecuteScalar` instead:

```
public void invoiceno()
{
    try
    {
        var sql = "SELECT MAX(invoid) FROM sales";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        var maxInvNum = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() + 1;

        label4.Text = $"E-{maxInvNum:000000}";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.Write(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

You use string formatting methods (the above is an interpolated string). You could also use:

```
label4.Text = "E-" + maxInvNum.ToString("000000");
```

Which would give you essentially the same thing.

Comment: label4.Text = "E-" + maxInvNum.ToString("000000"); this line error sir maxInvNum

Comment: Please see the edit I made with the integer cast on the `var maxInvNum = ...` line.

Comment: label4.Text = "E-" + maxInvNum.ToString("000000"); still errot this line and label4.Text = $"E-{maxInvNum:000000}";

Comment: What is the error that you see?

Comment: label4.Text = $"E-{maxInvNum:000000}";   error displayed expected;

Comment: Can you screenshot the error, maybe there is a translation error but that "error text" doesn't mean anything to me. From the other answer you are calling this in the `FormLoad` event? Try the `OnShown` instead, the controls aren't created when the form is loaded so you may get an error saying that the control handle wasn't created.